# Linear Regression Training with timeseries date

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I am new to sklearn. I have an assignment to do Linear Regression, Logistic Regression, etc. I am trying to create data to compare the results. My data looks like:

```
Closing_Price   Daily_Returns   Daily_Returns_1 Daily_Returns_2 Daily_Returns_3 Daily_Returns_4 Daily_Returns_5
Date                            
1980-12-22  0.53    0.058269    0.040822    0.042560    0.021979    -0.085158   -0.040005
1980-12-23  0.55    0.037041    0.058269    0.040822    0.042560    0.021979    -0.085158
1980-12-24  0.58    0.053110    0.037041    0.058269    0.040822    0.042560    0.021979
1980-12-26  0.63    0.082692    0.053110    0.037041    0.058269    0.040822    0.042560
1980-12-29  0.64    0.015748    0.082692    0.053110    0.037041    0.058269    0.040822
```

What I want to do is use sklearn linear regression for start to calculate and plot the results along with Daily Returns. This is what I am doing:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression as lr
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression as lor
X = apple['Closing_Price'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = apple['Daily_Returns'].values.reshape(-1,1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2)
LinReg = lr()
LinReg.fit(X_train,y_train)
LinRegPred = LinReg.predict(X_test)
```

My question: Is it possible to create a 2D array with Column 1 as the index values from the dataframe of the original data set and column 2 as the predicted Linear Regression results?

Where `apple.index` :

```
DatetimeIndex(['1980-12-22', '1980-12-23', '1980-12-24', '1980-12-26',
               '1980-12-29', '1980-12-30', '1980-12-31', '1981-01-02',
               '1981-01-05', '1981-01-06',
               ...
               '2019-05-22', '2019-05-23', '2019-05-24', '2019-05-28',
               '2019-05-29', '2019-05-30', '2019-05-31', '2019-06-03',
               '2019-06-04', '2019-06-05'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=9695, freq=None)
```

Comment: So the first column should be `y_train` for instance and the second column `LinRegPred` ? If your question is how to make a matrix from two arrays `a` and `b`, the answer is `np.transpose(np.array([a,b]))`

Comment: @dallonsi edited my question. I hope it makes it more clear.

Comment: For the first column, something like : `apple.index[:len(y_train)]` maybe ?

Comment: @dallonsi Here is the core issue, when the training set are selected they are random. Hence we don't know which values in the training/test set belong to which index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make the `train_test_split` rather on the data frame

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression as lr
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression as lor
import numpy as np

data_train, data_test,  = train_test_split(apple,test_size = 0.2)
X_train = data_train['Closing_Price'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y_train = data_train['Daily_Returns'].values.reshape(-1,1)
X_test = data_test['Closing_Price'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y_test = data_test['Daily_Returns'].values.reshape(-1,1)
LinReg = lr()
LinReg.fit(X_train,y_train)
LinRegPred = LinReg.predict(X_test)
```

and then you can just acess your index and creating the 2D array as follows :

```
from datetime import datetime
predictedWithIndexes = [list(index.astype(str)), list(LinRegPred)]
pdi = pd.DataFrame(predictedWithIndexes)
pdi = pdi.T
pdi.columns = ['Date','Predicted_Linear_Regression']
pdi['Predicted_Linear_Regression'] = pdi['Predicted_Linear_Regression'].astype(float)
pdi['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(pdi['Date'].str[0])
```

I wish that I have answered your question

Comment: when I run second part python does not like the concatenation throws invalid type promotion error

Comment: oh forgot numpy does not support different types of variables on a single array, I guess you could use a list then   ``` predictedWithIndexes = [list(index), list(LinRegPred)]```